# How can I mention 2 users in a discord bot message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm using discord.js.

I'm trying to make a bot command that will output the following output:

```
Welcome, (mentioned user 1) and (mentioned user 2), enjoy your stay!
```

When the syntax is:

```
(prefix) getaroom for (mentioned user 1) (mentioned user 2)
```

Help?!

Comment: You can try using [message.mentions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions). Can you also share what you've tried?

Comment: @IceBotYT I used message.mentions.users.first() for the first one but I dont know how to do the second one

Comment: Can you try `message.mentions.users.second()`?

Comment: @IceBotYT, it threw an error. message.mentions.users.second is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `message.mentions.users.first()` works well for the first mentioned user when it comes to wanting a second, third or maybe even fourth we start running into various issues.
The way I prefer resolving this issue is by running the `.forEach()` function through `message.mentions.users`.
Example:

```js
var prefix = 'yourPrefixHere'; //Defining your prefix
client.on('message', message => { //Adding your event listener
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + 'getaroom') { //When the command is entered
        if (!message.mentions.first()) return message.channel.send(`You have not defined your users.`); //If the message did not include mentioned users
        var count = 0; //To find out what user we're on.
        let user1; //Defining the users
        let user2; //Defining the users
        message.mentions.forEach(user => {
            count++; //Adding one onto the count variable
            if (count >= 3) return; //If the user mentioned more than two users return
            if (count === 1) user1 = message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id); //Getting the first mentioned user
            else user2 = message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id); //Getting the second mentioned user
        });
        //Rest of your code...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the [`message.mentions.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=users) collection to an array of user IDs with [`Collection.prototype.keyArray()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=keyArray).

```js
const [first, second] = message.mentions.users.keyArray();

if (!first || !second)
 return message.channel.send('You need to mention two users!');

message.channel.send(`Welcome, <@${first}> and <@${second}>, enjoy your stay!`);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you convert them to a string with the @ symbol in front of it does it work.  I'm pretty sure this used to work when I worked on bots in python.

Comment: like <@(userid)>?

Comment: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions  I am not a js developer, but it looks like mentions is a collection which I'm assuming you can index into.